# Pandas read data without header or index

Tags: python, pandas, csv, numpy

Here is the **.csv** file :

```
0   0   1   1   1   0   1   1   0   1   1   1   1
0   1   1   0   1   0   1   1   0   1   0   0   1
0   0   1   1   0   0   1   1   1   0   1   1   1
0   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   2
0   1   1   1   0   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1
0   0   0   1   1   1   0   1   0   0   0   1   1
0   0   0   0   1   1   0   0   1   0   1   0   2
0   1   1   0   1   1   1   1   0   1   1   1   1
0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   0   1
0   1   1   1   0   1   1   0   0   0   0   1   1
```

where the first column must be indices like `(0,1,2,3,4 ...)` but due to some reasons they are zeros. Is there any way to make them normal when reading the csv file with pandas.read_csv ?

i use

```
df = pd.read_csv(file,delimiter='\t',header=None,names=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12])
```

and getting something like:

```
    1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  11  12
0   0   1   1   1   0   1   1   0   1   1   1   1
0   1   1   0   1   0   1   1   0   1   0   0   1
0   0   1   1   0   0   1   1   1   0   1   1   1
0   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   2
0   1   1   1   0   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1
0   0   0   1   1   1   0   1   0   0   0   1   1
0   0   0   0   1   1   0   0   1   0   1   0   2
0   1   1   0   1   1   1   1   0   1   1   1   1
0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   0   1
0   1   1   1   0   1   1   0   0   0   0   1   1
```

and it's nearly i need, but first column (indices) is still zeros. Can pandas for example ignore this first column of zeros and automatically generate new indices to get this:

```
  0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12
0 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 1  1  0  1
1 0 1 0 1 1 0 0 0 1 1  1  1  2
2 0 1 1 1 0 0 1 1 1 1  1  1  2
```

Comment: `pd.read_csv(file, header=None, index_col=False, sep='\t')`, you don't need the `names` param either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why fuss over `read_csv`? Use `np.loadtxt`:

```
pd.DataFrame(np.loadtxt(file, dtype=int))

   0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  11  12
0   0   0   1   1   1   0   1   1   0   1   1   1   1
1   0   1   1   0   1   0   1   1   0   1   0   0   1
2   0   0   1   1   0   0   1   1   1   0   1   1   1
3   0   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   2
4   0   1   1   1   0   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1
5   0   0   0   1   1   1   0   1   0   0   0   1   1
6   0   0   0   0   1   1   0   0   1   0   1   0   2
7   0   1   1   0   1   1   1   1   0   1   1   1   1
8   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   1   1   0   1
9   0   1   1   1   0   1   1   0   0   0   0   1   1
```

The default delimiter is whitespace, and no headers/indexes are read in by default. Column types are also not inferred, since the `dtype` is specified to be `int`. All in all, this is a very succinct and powerful alternative.

Answer (score 21):

You might want      `index_col=False`

```
df = pd.read_csv(file,delimiter='\t', 
                 header=None, 
                 index_col=False)
```

From the [Docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html),

> If you have a malformed file with delimiters at the end of each line,
>   you might consider index_col=False to force pandas to *not* use the
>   first column as the index